# How to avoid duplicated records in core data - ios

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm new in iOS, Swift. My application has one entity named "Category" in a relationship to many entities named "Movies".

"Movies" entities are changing, according to data that I get from a url. I'm looking for a way not to have duplicated movies records in each category, and I can't think of an easy way to do it.

Comment: do the entities have a unique id?

Comment: No, they don't. The category has a constraint, the movies don't.

Comment: what is you are asking about ? title says duplicate but question says don't ?

Comment: do you have it setup that Movie and Category has a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: It's a one to many relationship. Very annoying that such a basic need can not be easily implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Core-data does not have a built in way to ensure uniqueness.  You have to manage that yourself.  But it is not that hard.  Before every insert/update do a fetch - if it does not exist then create it, it if already exists then update it.  If you are updating many at a time (for example from a network request that has updates for many entities) then fetch all of then in a single fetch request and then create or update as needed.

Generally these fetches are done using uniqueIds for each entity. If you don't have any uniqueId for you entities then you have a deeper problem than core data.  You could have two movies with the same name, or one movie that has different names.  If you don't have anything that says the same, then you fundamentally don't have any way to know if you need to make another entity or update an existing one. It is possible that you can use the movie name, but I would not recommend that.  I suggest that you look closer at your server api and see if there is a uniqueId that is served, and if there is none then you have to have it fixed by the server team.

Comment: When you get new data search for an existing Movie by name.  If you find one then update it, if you don't then create it.  (Again this is a BAD idea - your system you have uniqueIds for each movie.  I would be really surprised if the server was not giving you a uniqueId).